# How to ask in Meta with only 1 reputation?

Tags: discussion

I’m trying to clarify the answer of a user on a question.

However, I cannot reply to his post (ie: comment on his answer. thanks TheGrandPackard for pointing out this possible ambiguity) in order to ask directly, as that requires 20 rep.

I cannot ask how to use this site in Meta (in order to get the desired clarification) as that requires 5 rep.

As far as I can tell my question is not answered in FAQs or help.

How then am I able to get the clarification I desire without first wasting time in order to get enough votes/rep for me to be able to ask the question I need to ask?

- [How to get excel row numbers to skip the header - user522468's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/480777/how-to-get-excel-row-numbers-to-skip-the-header/564830#)

If someone with enough rep wanted to ask `user522468` for me my question is: I tried entering `=ROW(A2:A93)-1` into cell `A1` and all that happened was A1 showed the numeral 1. Is this what you are suggesting and if so what result did you get?

Comment: This question will probably be closed as off-topic on SU, but why don't you edit your question to include a link to the post in question and what you need to ask and perhaps someone will post it to a comment for you.

Comment: You could also post a new question with your specific issue and include a link to the other post for context.

Comment: Do something else on this site that will earn you reputation.  Look for questions to answer.  Ask a question, that is on-topic for this site.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, fixer1234. Thanks, Zoredache. Someone upvoting this q has given me sufficient rep to post in meta :)

Comment: This will get migrated to Meta, and you now have the rep to interact there.  You won't need to post again, and the alternatives are already here in comments, so you don't really need Meta.

Comment: And what, exactly, is your question?  What clarification are you looking for?

Comment: I just followed your advice and edited it into my question.

Comment: Just noticed that that user hasn't been back since posting the answer, and chances are slim of somebody else stumbling across your comment and posting an answer for you in "real" time.  You also wouldn't be able to interact if someone did.  Your best be would be to ask a new question with your actual problem.  Link to the other question and mention that it is similar.  Include your experience trying to implement that solution.  That will put your question in the "active" list where people will see it, and you will be able to interact on your own thread with follow-up questions/comments.

Comment: Actually, I just looked at that original question and the answer you want clarification on.  I think it's a bad answer.  My read of the question is the OP wanted to modify how Excel does its row numbering.  The answer just makes a pseudo-code suggestion for how to adjust row counts in calculations with a missing first row.  It doesn't work for you because the answer doesn't work at all, except in a trivial sense--subtract 1 from the row count for the missing row.

Comment: I see. Do you think then that I should abandon attempting to implement user522468's suggestion in favour of another?

Comment: Only if you want a working solution.  :-)  That answer should probably be a candidate for deletion because it doesn't address the original question and isn't really useful for any purpose except to confuse people.

Answer (score -6):

All users have the privilege to comment on an answer starting with 1 reputation. You have the ability to create posts:

> Create Posts
>
> Privilege Type: Creation Privilege Awarded At: 1 Reputation
>
> What is asking and answering questions? The most basic privilege of
>   all -- the right to ask a question, and the right to contribute an
>   answer. This is generally available to everyone, regardless of
>   reputation level.

This is available on the privileges page here: https://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-posts

Comment: Unfortunately, commenting at 1 rep is limited to your own thread.  Commenting anywhere requires 50 rep.

Comment: Exactly!

Thus I was unable to ask the user for clarification.

Now that I have enough rep to use Meta, I can't seem to find it! =-/

Comment: Thanks to both of you though.